# Why does my Azure ML endpoint give me the error: Content: b"run() missing 1 required positional argument: 'method'

Tags: python, json, jupyter-notebook, azure-web-app-service, azureml-python-sdk

I'm trying to make a request to my Azure ML model via a Azure Notebook, that has deployed on an endpoint.

I confirmed the JSON submission via Swagger JSON and my python code looks like this:

```
data =  {
  'data': [36,0,0,1,1,1],
  'method': 'predict_proba'
}

body = str.encode(json.dumps(data))

output = service.run(body)

print(output)
```

But upon running, I get the following error:

```
Received bad response from service. More information can be found by calling `.get_logs()` on the webservice object.
Response Code: 502
Headers: {'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Content-Length': '54', 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8', 'Date': 'Mon, 27 Mar 2023 04:10:40 GMT', 'Server': 'nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)', 'X-Ms-Client-Request-Id': '8058cc94-29ae-474b-adc8-e1487ecebf03', 'X-Ms-Request-Id': '8058cc94-29ae-474b-adc8-e1487ecebf03', 'X-Ms-Run-Function-Failed': 'True', 'X-Ms-Server-Version': 'azmlinfsrv/0.7.7', 'X-Request-Id': '6c539f4c-1b61-4b2d-8406-258cb6e5335d'}
Content: b"run() missing 1 required positional argument: 'method'"
```

I have tried to find the issue but, .run() doesn't have a method parameter.

Anyone know why I get this error?